# A Collatz generalization and approximation of a bounded-unbounded point of Collatz-like Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dynamical-systems, collatz-conjecture

I have been working on Collatz-like functions to test the probabilistic heuristic argument in favor of all trajectories being bounded (ending in a cycle) and have come up with a generalization to test this argument empirically. This leads me to two questions.

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}$. The Collatz function states that the following iterated map will eventually equal to 1:

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if}\  2\mid n\\
3n+1, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

My generalization is as follows:
Let $G:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{Z}$ defined as

$$G(x) =
\begin{cases}
x/2,  & \text{if}\  2\mid x\\
2\lceil ax \rceil, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

where $a, x \in \mathbb{R}$. The Collatz function is the case when $a = 1.5$. Likewise, the $5n+1$ problem is the case when $a=2.5$.

I conjecture in line with the heuristic argument that if $-2 \leq a \leq 2$ then for any $x_0$, repeated iteration of $G$ on $x_0$ will yield a bounded trajectory. However, if $a>2$ or $a<-2$, for some $x_0$, repeated iteration of $G$ on $x_0$ will yield an unbounded trajectory. Note, $G(x)$ is bounded if for all $x_0$ we end in a cycle whereas unbounded means that G has at least one trajectory that diverges to infinity.

1. **Is this a known generalization of the Collatz function?** I have check as much as I could and found only discontinuous generalizations such as [1](https://scholarship.richmond.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1496&context=honors-theses), [2](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL21/Choi/choi10.pdf), and [3](http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/papers/2004/2004-lesjohn.pdf).  On the other hand, $G(x)$ is continuous in the sense that it allows for both $x$ and $a$ to be any real numbers. Having this flexibility provides a way to test the probabilistic heuristic argument in favor of bounded trajectories by varying $a$ as close to 2 as possible, i.e. if $log(|a|) + log(1/2) < 0$, then for all $x_0$, iterations of $G(x)$ on $x_0$ will yield a cycle.
2. The function $H$ below is more global than $G$. Empirically, a bounded-unbounded point seems to exist for $H$ somewhere in the range  $c \leq 2b^2$. **Is there a better way to approximate the bounded-unbounded point for the generalization $H$ than testing different values of $c$ for a given value of $b$**.

$$H(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{b},  & \text{if}\  b\mid x\\
b\lceil \frac{cx}{b^2} \rceil, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
where $b,c \in \mathbb{N}$. The Collatz function is when $b = 2$ and $c = 6$.

Using Excel, when $b=3$, for $c \leq 16$, H appears bounded for all $x$ but for $c \geq 17$ it appears unbounded. Similarly, when $b = 5$, for $c \leq 35$, H appears bounded for all $x$ but for $c \geq 36$ it appears unbounded. For $b=7$ the demarcation point appears to be $c=65$. Taking the ratio $\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}$ where $c_{max}$ is the bounded-unbounded demarcation  point, gives

$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=2.0$ when $b = 2$
$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=1.8$ when $b = 3$
$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=1.5$ when $b = 4$
$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=1.4$ when $b = 5$
$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=1.4$ when $b = 6$
$\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}=1.3$ when $b = 7$

Seems that as $b \to \infty$ then, $\frac{c_{max}}{b^2}\to1$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I observe that $G$ takes any $x \in \Bbb{R} \smallsetminus \Bbb{Z}$ to $G(x) \in \Bbb{Z}$, so letting $x$ be non-integral doesn't add anything.

Comment: I'm curious: How does your analysis categorize the eventual behaviour of $19$ under iteration of $G$ when $a = 9/4$?  I find it is cyclic, with period $764$...

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, I would say that the closer '$a$'  approaches 2 from the right, the longer some cycles will be. Likewise, the closer '$a$' approaches 2 from the left, the longer it takes for $x$ to reach a cycle. So you may expect longer cycles if $a = 2.01$. On the other hand, the closer '$a$' is to $0$, the faster $x$ reaches a cycle.

Comment: I'm not asking about your conjecture.  I'm asking about your Excel calculations about a specific data point.

Comment: Using Pari/GP (instead of excel) confirms @ericTowers cycle. Simply said, $g°^{764}(86)=86$

Comment: @EricTowers I completely misinterpreted your question. It is true, as Gottfried Helm pointed out, that when $a = 9/4$, $G^{764} $$(19)=19$  where  $G^i(x)$ is the $i$th iteration. This is expected. The two categories that values of $a$ will produce are all cycles (trivial or nontrivial) or at least one diverging trajectory (with trivial and/or nontrivial cycles).

Comment: Hmm, it seems the excel-calculation is wrong here. Pari/GP gives the sequence of iterates `19, [86,43,...,344,172],[86,43, ...` (where I've inserted the brackets to make the cycle better visible). The $19$ is ***not*** part of a cycle, so $G^{764}(19)=172$ instead, and only $G(19)=86$ is part/is beginning of a cycle. So if actually Excel gave $G(19)=19$ there must have been some numerical error... (and I may advertize for using something like Pari/GP for your calculations)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms You are correct. An oversight on my part. The formula I used in excel, with 19 in A1,  is =IF(MOD(A1,2)=0,A1/2,CEILING(9/4*A1,1)*2). Have you come across any counterexamples to the conjecture concerning G(x)? I haven't so far.

Comment: Math777 - no counterexamples so far, but I'm just playing a bit around. $G(x)$ is a nice idea, indeed, but I don't think I'm going to involve myself too much...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Do you mind sharing your Pari/gp function. I posted a question in Stackoverflow but that site seems overwhelming busy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524440/how-to-write-an-iterated-function-in-pari-gp). You could post it there. Thanks.

Comment: Math777 - see q&d Pari/GP approach for documentation in the new answer. Hope I didn't refer too much to my user-specific functions ("msep(matrix,columns)" to distribute the entries of a matrix in "columns" many columns) is one but can be omitted)

Answer (score 1):

According to request of the asker, here is some Pari/GP -code, partly function-definitions, partly experimenting to get list of results.

```
\\ test collatz with *real* bases for existence of cycles and/or divergence
\\ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340764/a-collatz-generalization-and-approximating-the-bounded-unbounded-point-of-collat
\\ example set global variable "base" to some example value:

  base=9/4

g(x)=if(! (x % 2),x/2,2*ceil(base*x))

\\ alternative. g1(x) works on and produces only odd numbers. May be more
\\ efficient
g1(x)=my(A);A=valuation(x,2);x>>=A;x=2*ceil(base*x);A=valuation(x,2);x>>=A

  \\ print 800 steps of iterations, distributed over 5 columns ("msep(...,5)"), 
  \\ beginning at a0=19 ("msep()" is user defined function)
printp( msep(Mat(vectorv(800,r,if(r==1,a0=19,a0=g(a0)))),5))

  \\ print the same, with a0=86, in one column but showing the index as well:
for(k=1,800,if(k==1,a0=86,a0=g(a0));if(a0==86,print([k,a0])))


  \\ print 800 steps of iterations, distributed over 10 columns, 
  \\ beginning at a0=19 ("msep()" is user defined function)
  \\ we see, that a0=19 is not itself cyclic! but g(19)=86 is!
printp(msep(Mat(vectorv(800,r,if(r==1,a0=19,a0=g(a0)))),10))
```

Here we use two example bases, and call a loop, which checks for cycles in $a_0=1..999$ (only odd $a_0$) and cycle-lengthes of at most $10\,000$ iterations steps:

```
fmt(2000);base=sqrt(5);fmt(200) \\ use another base. Take care, that
 \\ over many iterations numbers with many digits shall occur; choose
 \\ accordingly *big* decimal precision! (here 2000 dec digits)


fmt(2000);base=Pi-1;fmt(200)
  \\ or try this base near 2

\\ a loop to find cycles and protocol them:
{print("Base:",base);cyclist=List();
 forstep(a0=1,999,2,
   dir=Map();
   a1=a2=a0;found=0;ix1=ix2=0;mapput(dir,a1,0);
   for(k=1,10000,         \\ test for cycles with length up to 10 000
          a1=g1(a1);      \\ use g1() to document only odd steps
          if(!mapisdefined(dir,a1,&ix1),mapput(dir,a1,k);next());
          a2=a1;found=ix2=k;break();
       );
   if(!found, listput(cyclist,Str(a0," --- nothing found"));next());
     \\ find minimal element of the found cycle 
   len=ix2-ix1; mina1=a1;for(k=1,len,a1=g1(a1);mina1=min(a1,mina1));
     \\ document the parameters for this a0, be it cycle or not:
   listput(cyclist,
      strprintf("%3d : %3d-->%3d cyclen:%3d enter cyc at val:%4d at pos:%3d \n",a0,mina1,mina1,len,a2,ix1));
   next();
   );
   cyclist=Mat(Col(cyclist)); \\ convert "cyclist" from Map to Mat
   printp(cyclist[1..8,]) } \\ show the first 8 entries.
```

This gave the following protocol (base = $\pi-1$). Only odd numbers were documented (using function $g_1(x)$) :

```
    1 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   3 at pos:  1 \n
    3 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   3 at pos:  0 \n
    5 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  1 \n
    7 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  0 \n
    9 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  2 \n
   11 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  0 \n
   13 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  1 \n
   15 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  15 at pos:  0 \n
   17 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  3 \n
   19 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  41 at pos:  1 \n
   21 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  4 \n
   23 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  4 \n
   25 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  3 \n
   27 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  2 \n
   29 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  1 \n
   31 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  4 \n
   33 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  33 at pos:  0 \n
   35 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:1639 at pos: 46 \n
   37 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  2 \n
   39 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  5 \n
   41 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  41 at pos:  0 \n
   43 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  5 \n
   45 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  3 \n
   47 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  33 at pos: 25 \n
   49 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos: 18 \n
   51 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  7 \n
   53 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  33 at pos:  3 \n
   55 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  6 \n
   57 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  33 at pos:  2 \n
   59 :   3-->  3 cyclen:  8 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  5 \n
                                            61 --- nothing found
   63 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  0 \n
   65 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 10 enter cyc at val:1639 at pos: 47 \n
   ...
```

and this is the version using $g(x)$ which allows to display even values in the orbit (which also means, the documented cycle-lengthes are longer than with $g_1(x)$):

```
    3 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:   3 at pos:  0 \n
    5 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos:  1 \n
    7 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:   7 at pos:  0 \n
    9 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos:  5 \n
   11 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  11 at pos:  0 \n
   13 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  14 at pos:  3 \n
   15 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  15 at pos:  0 \n
   17 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos:  9 \n
   19 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  82 at pos:  1 \n
   21 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  14 at pos: 13 \n
   23 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val: 126 at pos: 10 \n
   25 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val: 126 at pos:  7 \n
   27 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val: 126 at pos:  4 \n
   29 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val: 126 at pos:  1 \n
   31 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos: 13 \n
   33 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  33 at pos:  0 \n
   35 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val:3278 at pos:136 \n
   37 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos:  7 \n
   39 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  14 at pos: 17 \n
   41 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  41 at pos:  0 \n
   43 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val: 126 at pos: 14 \n
   45 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  14 at pos: 11 \n
   47 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  66 at pos: 77 \n
   49 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos: 57 \n
   51 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos: 23 \n
   53 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  66 at pos:  9 \n
   55 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos: 20 \n
   57 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  66 at pos:  6 \n
   59 :   3-->  3 cyclen: 25 enter cyc at val:  22 at pos: 17 \n
                                            61 --- nothing found
   63 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val:  63 at pos:  0 \n
   65 :  63--> 63 cyclen: 31 enter cyc at val:3278 at pos:140 \n
  ...
```

Comment: Appreciated. Would it have been better to post this answer over  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524440/how-to-write-an-iterated-function-in-pari-gp as requested?

Comment: @Math777 - hmm, don't know. But feel free to copy&paste this answer to any place you like, I'm currently much involved with different things... :-(